# WCF Rest Change name of root return element

Tags: c#, .net, xml, wcf, rest

I have

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
    ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml,
    RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml,
    BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
    UriTemplate = "projects/{projectname}")]
[return: MessageParameter(Name = "ProjectId")]
Guid CreateProject(String projectName);
```

But this still returns

```
<guid 
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">00000000-0000-0000-0000-00000000</guid>
```

How do I replace "guid" with ProjectId?

```
public Guid CreateProject(String projectName)
{
     return Guid.Empty;
}
```

If I change the OperationContract BodyStyle to `WrappedResponse` I get:

```
<CreateProjectResponse 
    xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
    <ProjectId>00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000</ProjectId>
</CreateProjectResponse>
```

Which is almost what I want, but I don't want  unnecessarily wrapped.

Comment: And what does CreateProject returns? Valid guid?

Comment: show more code => you have only posted the interface and a result... but not the service implementation.

Comment: It returns a guid, in the format in my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest solution is to

```
return new XElement("ProjectId", Guid.Empty);
```

Not really what I wanted, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

You become what you have defined. You have defined to receive empty GUID in XML form and it returns to you empty GUID in XML. All is right.

Maybe you need convert GUID to some kind of string id, then `Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N")`

When you aren't expecting xml then you need to fit attributes and use HTTP Accept Header from client, for example for Json Accept: `application/json`, or string - `plain/text`

**UPD:**
Now a little bit clear. Your actually ask how to change XML structure. I recommend you for standard types use standard XML structure because you already have implemented from the box XML formatters. Anyway when you need to change formatters, you can do it by extending the `WebHttpBehavior` and overriding the `WebHttpBehavior.GetReplyDispatchFormatter` method to return our own custom implementation of System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.IDispatchFormatter (as example read [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2011/08/16/wcf-extensibility-webhttpbehavior.aspx))

I want also just mention, that you are using WCF 4 REST, and this technology is legacy. When you are dealing not with legacy project or maintenance, then I recommend you to use [ASP.NET Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api), because this and many other things could be done there much more easier.

Comment: I don't believe I have defined it to accept an empty Guid. My question is how do I format the returned XML to say <ProjectId>000-000-00</ProjectId> instead of <Guid></Guid>?

Comment: I've answered in UPD section in answer